# Can I use 12/2 NM-B wire for basement outlets?

Tags: electrical, wiring, drywall, basement, receptacle

Can I use 12/2 NM-B  wire for basement outlets?

Also can I use 15 AMP outlets and switches with 12/2 NM-B wire?

Comment: Is it a finished, or unfinished basement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use nonmetallic sheathed cable in basements, as long as you follow a few rules.

If you're using 12 AWG cable, and you're installing the cable at angles to the joists. You'll have to pull the cable through [bored holes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10661/33), or along running boards. You cannot staple the cable along the bottom of the joist.

When you come down the wall, you'll have to protect the cable in some way. This could be in conduit, or by installing a wood framing member (2x4) for the cable to attach to.  If you use the framing member, the cable will have to attach to the side not the face of the member.

[This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/9340/33) will provide code references.

---

Yes, you can use 12 AWG conductors with 15 ampere rated receptacles and switches.  You'll have to use the screw terminals, instead of the push-in terminals. As most push-in terminals on these devices, are only rated for 14 AWG conductors.

Comment: I highly suggest cutting yourself some kind of standard height length of conduit all at once, and anchor with some conduit straps for your outlets. Provides a good deal of protection in a basement. It's what I did in my basement. Very minimally invasive if you ask me.

Comment: @Kumar If you bore holes in the joists to run the cable, make sure you research the requirements for doing that. You can only run so many cables through one hole, but there are rules to follow for structural integrity. If your joists are prefabricated, find the manufacturer's specifications for cutting holes in them. If they're solid wood joists, don't bore any holes close to the edges or within a foot or two of the ends.